# Daily Mishnah Study - Reference Request

Tags: product-recommendation, mishna

Putting into action another of the suggestions I received (@SAH) for "One Jewish Practice," I would like to begin daily studying.

Specifically, I would like to participate in a Daily Mishnah study. This seems like a perfect time as Bava Kamma begins this week. I found the text generously available in Hebrew and English at Sefaria.org

To that end, I have found several websites that also generously offer teachings on a daily basis:

https://www.mishnahyomit.com

http://mishnah.co/about

http://dafyomi.co.il/calendars/myomi/mishnah_indexmenu.php

I would appreciate mention of any other sources of teaching (in English), either audio or video, or even written, that I might consider. If any bring in Kehati, that would be nice.

Thanks

**EDIT** After learning several days at this site http://mishnah.co/about, I find it very appealing and engaging.

Comment: Kahati has an iPhone app with; and even some English translations in it iirc

Comment: This is not personal advice, it is general advice for sources of Mishna Yomi classes - doesn't depend on the OP personal situation, although if the OP could bring criteria by which to judge answers, that would be even better

Comment: Look into ArtScrolls new Mishnah translations, and the app/website Kol Halashon

Comment: Not really an answer, but I find the [OU's audio](https://www.ou.org/torah/gemara-series/mishna-yomit/#?) to be good for review while commuting since it's generally (with some variation between speakers) to the point and unembellished. Also, great choice of a practice to take on. I'm a fan!

Comment: To second @WAF (and this was going to be my answer), the OU has a pretty solid app for Android (and probably iPhone, but I only have experience with Android) for their lectures. It's a simple and clean interface for their lectures that they have in their website.